# Compile error when explicitly calling the base class destructor on a derived pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, destructor, placement-new

Just like the title says. The following contrived example seems to work on codepad: http://codepad.org/4cgGmvDQ and under GCC 4.1.2 on my Linux box.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<new>

class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase(){}
};

class B : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    virtual ~D(){ }
};

int main()
{
    void* p = malloc(sizeof(D));

    D* d = new(p) D();

    B* b = static_cast<B*>(d);

    b->~IBase();

    free(p);
}
```

But Visual Studio Pro 2012 11.0.61030.00 Update 4 fails with:

`main.cpp(30): error C2300: 'B' : class does not have a destructor called '~IBase'`

Obviously the example could easily be reworked to avoid the issue, but my actual code base doesn't give me any other options. Is anyone familiar with this particular failing of the Microsoft compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a MSVC bug; clang rejects your code as well.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't cast `b` to `IBase *`?

Comment: Thinking about it, that makes a tonne of sense! Thanks.

Comment: @T.C yes, that's the purpose of interfaces +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug in MSVC. From the standard, §3.4.5 [basic.lookup.classref]/p2-3 (quoting N3936, emphasis mine):

> If the *id-expression* in a class member access (5.2.5) is an
>   *unqualified-id*, [...]
>
> If the *unqualified-id* is `~type-name`, the *type-name* is looked up
>   in the context of the entire *postfix-expression*. If the type `T` of
>   the object expression is of a class type `C`, the type-name is also
>   looked up in the scope of class `C`. **At least one of the lookups
>   shall find a name that refers to (possibly cv-qualified) `T`.**

In your code, `T` is `B`, and lookup for `IBase` obviously can't find a name that refers to `B`. Therefore, your code is ill-formed. If g++ accepts it, it's either a bug or an extension.

Since it sounds like the actual type `B` represents is "unspeakable" in your real code, but `IBase` is OK to write, the simplest solution would be simply to cast `b` to `IBase *`.

Comment: Would `b->~IBase()` be valid had there been no user defined `~B()`?

Comment: @RSahu No, the problem is not caused by name hiding (and you get an implicitly `~B()` anyway if you don't define one). The problem is that the language expects the type you named to match the type of the object.

Comment: What does *If the type `T` of the object expression is of a class type `C`* mean? When would `T` and `C` be different?

Comment: @RSahu `T` may not be a class type (in which case it's a pseudo-destructor call that does nothing). This basically makes it possible to write generic code that destroys an object without having to figure out whether the type passed in is a class type or not.

Comment: Are you saying something like `char buf[100]; int* ip = new (buf) int; ip->~int();` is valid C++?

Comment: @RSahu That's not, because `int` is a keyword, but `typedef int INT; void *buf = malloc(100); int* ip = new (buf) int; ip->~INT();` is valid C++ (so is `ip->INT::~INT();`). See 5.2.4 [expr.pseudo].

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug. As to "why" it fails, I have no answer. The workaround for your example may be:

b->IBase::~IBase();

Comment: That disables virtual dispatch.

Comment: @T.C. good point, I was about to fix it, but obviously virtual dispatch is the whole point.

Comment: @T.C. since i can't comment directly under your posts, could you explain the paragraph you provided?

Comment: @HighPredator Basically, it says that when you write something in the form `b.~Something();` where `b`'s type is `B`, the compiler must be able to find a name `Something` that refers to (possibly `const` and/or `volatile`-qualified) `B`.

Answer (score -1):

Base Class Destructors are invoked automatically. If you call the base class destructor manually then when the object gets destroyed it will be invoked a second time.

Comment: @fauxCoder Yea I missed that.